# A series in fractional powers

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am trying to expand the given function of $r$ in a series:

$$\frac{1}{\left (t \left (t-k \right) + i r k  \right)^\delta}$$ where $k$ is a finite positive number, $\delta$ lies between $0$ and $1$ and $t$ is the time. The difficulty lies in the fact that $r$ is a very small number, so small that even its 1st order is supposed to vanish. **But** since $0<\delta=(1/m)<1$, we want to preserve all orders less than 1, namely

$$r^{j} \neq 0$$ if $j<1$.

Excuse me if my language is sloppy since formally I study physics. But this is the core of the problem. I want to expand the given function in fractional powers of $r$ such that the series is assumed to die near the first order.

Also, is it possible to find the real and imaginary parts of the above function in closed form, given that $\delta$ is a fraction. I ask so since there must be some branch cut issues.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Let $a:=t(t-k)$ and $s:=irk/a$ (of the same order as $r$), your function of $r$ becomes $a^{-\delta}g(s)$ and you want to expand $g(s):=(1+s)^{-\delta}$?

Comment: Which "fractional powers" of $r$ are you hoping to expand the function in? Unlike the nice discrete integer powers, rationals are dense. Unlike the integers, rationals are not well-ordered, giving you a definitive sequence of partial sums. Please be more specific about what you want to do.